# Reactjs multiselect listbox

Tags: reactjs, html-select

I have implemented a multi-select listbox in react js which looks like this

[image]

Problem is when I move any option from selectbox 1 to selectbox 2, it will move the option but will also gray out the next option in the selectbox 2 which seems like as if 2nd option is also selected even though it is not, to select that 2nd option, I first have to select some other option then select the desired option again.

I have used `onChange={this.handleInputChange}` on select field

And function is defined as: `handleInputChange(evt){this.setState({......});}`

And I've created a custom component to render the select: `<Select list={this.state.list} />`

So whenever I press the button to move options from one list to other, the `list` object is manipulated which is the array which contains all objects.

What I want is, whenever the option is moved from one list to other, select box should not have any option showing as selected.

Comment: if you could make your code available in a sandbox that will be great, because it's hard to say what's going on without knowing what you have in your handleInputChange function